# cleanUpFlutterEngine() of FlutterActivity is not being called sometimes when I kill the app

Tags: android, flutter

In my flutter application I am doing some Android Native cleanup on app kill. So I am overriding `cleanUpFlutterEngine()` and doing the cleanup inside it. The problem is `cleanUpFlutterEngine` is not being called always. I tried to identify the pattern but I couldn't find it.

I just wanted to know is it appropriate to keep cleanup stuff in `cleanUpFlutterEngine()` instead of `onDestroy()` ?

And why `cleanUpFlutterEngine()` not being called always on app kill ?.

Below are the logs in sequence (including lifecycle events) for the scenario (app launch then app kill).

**When the execution happens**

```
onCreate
configureFlutterEngine
onStart
onResume
onPause
onStop
onDestroy
cleanUpFlutterEngine
```

**When the execution does not happen**

```
onCreate
configureFlutterEngine
onStart
onResume
onPause
onStop
onDestroy
```

**I am not getting any errors/warning in the logcat.**

Comment: Just curious on why you didn't do it in `onDestroy`, which is a more generic method that's meant for developers to override and add stuff.

Comment: @WSBT Actually that part of code was written 2 years ago.  Do you know how this is different from onDestroy() ? And what can be the use of cleanUpFlutterEngine() ?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you move your logic into `onDestroy` event instead.

Looking at the function names, you can see a pattern here. Usually, anything that begins with the word "on", like `onClick`, `onLoad`, `onDestroy`, are "events" that fire in particular situations. These events are typically there for developers (you) to implement their application-specific business logic.

On the other hand, the function name `cleanUpFlutterEngine` begins with a verb, and it's meant to do exactly that - clean up the flutter engine. It's meant as a closed function that minds its own business, so you should not insert your business logic in there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but my question is different. Even to move my logic to `onDestroy` I will need a concrete reason.